# asp.net Textbox ID inside DIV C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, textbox

I have 2 textboxes with the ID="situps" and ID="pushups" The reason they're in Div's is because I need them to use number pads only when used on a tablet.  I was wondering if there was a way to retreive that ID in c#.  Here is the code for the textboxes:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <asp:TextBox ID="situps" runat="server" Height="16px"   
    ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" Width="108px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<input onblur="document.getElementById('<%=Sits.ClientID %>').value = this.value" type="tel" style="width: 86px" />

<div style="display:none">
        <asp:TextBox ID="pushups" runat="server" Height="16px" 
        ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" Width="108px"></asp:TextBox>
</div> 
<br />
    Push-ups <input onblur="document.getElementById('<%=Push.ClientID %>').value = 
    this.value" type="tel" style="width: 86px" />
<br />
```

I've figure out how to retrieve Labels within a formview, but can't figure out how to get DIV ID's from texboxes outside of formview.

Thanks!!!

Comment: are you referring to the wrapping divs without ids?

Comment: When their sitting on the top container of the page you could simply reference them directly: `situps.Text="10"`. A `DIV`(or `Panel`) is not implementing `INamingContainer`.

Comment: I think I've made a simple mistake.  I must've had duplicates of the names situps and pushups.  I am now able to grab the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've made a simple mistake. I must've had duplicates of the names situps and pushups. I am now able to grab the ID!!